# D3 charts - how to develop Map to filter ZIP code using dc.js and crossfilter

Tags: maps, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm developing a d3 charts dashboard using dc.js charts and crossfilter. We have to implement a map feature that shows U.S map and a user can see States and Zip code. User can zoom in to a map, select a ZIP code, that will filter the rest of the charts. We're trying to use this:

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/vc/index.html

Is it possible to use ZIP code (using longitude and latitude) instead of just states?

We also find 
http://chelm.github.io/esri-d3/css-sample.html

which have a zoom feature but only states. Though I looked at the code and it turns out the states are created using coordinates to draw the line for hover.

Is it possible to have a ZIP code implement to that map using longitude and latitude? I'm sorry I'm very new when working on the D3 map charts. I'm trying to research a possible solutions for our dashboard.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually how I've done this is to use two levels of choropleth, one at the state level and one at the zip code level. You can get geojson shape files for all the zip codes in the US. It's a bit taxing on the browser to draw all zip codes in the US but drawing all the zip codes in one state is quite feasible. That said, getting the zoom interaction is a bit of a trick. If you have space for it, it might be easier to keep the US map and state map as separate charts.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a React app using the GoogleMaps API and the npm packages "points-cluster" and "google-map-react". I got zip code lat/long data from [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666). I won't go into any more detail here because both npm packages have pretty good documentation. I got this up and running in under two days. Hope that gets you started!

Comment: Please write here the solution instead of including a link that could be broken in the future. Thanks!